# The js mousemove event cannot display the right debug information

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mousemove

I'm trying to implement tree drag feature, but when I debug mousemove event, it seems cannot work normally. I cannot find the real reason or something information related to this problem.

The whole code you can check in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7RkV5/3/

I have bind the event in the code `$(e.target).bind("mousemove", function(mme) {});` in the **handleDroppableOver** function, and I have already added some debug information(`debug("mouse position: x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ">>>>>>");`), but when I drag one element, it cannot output the debug information(I think mousemove event should response on every pixel mouse move, this information can only been seen in the condition that I drag very quickly)

So, is there anyone can help me? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason, it is because the cursorAt attribute, just change cursorAt: {left: 10, top: -40} to cursorAt: {left: 10, top: 0}

The debug information can display normally.

I think maybe when the top offset exceed 5, it will cannot work normally.